# An assembly language program that picks a data from a port and compare it to the value in a memory

Tags: assembly, x86, assemblies, nasm

```
in AX 10
cmp AX
cmp AX 10
```

can someone give me a clue on how to write an assembly language program for 16 bit intel processor that picks a data from a port compare the value with that in a memory and activate an activity like addition of both values, i was trying to make an effort above but am all confused

Comment: Did you try reading any relevant guides / tutorials / reference?

Comment: The lack of proper syntax in your "effort" suggests you should start with a basic tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Short description of `in` instruction: A byte, word or dword is read from "port" and placed in AL, AX or EAX respectively.  If the port number is in the range of 0-255 it can be specified as an immediate, otherwise the port number must be specified in DX. For example:

```
in ax, 10 ; read a word from port 10 into register ax
cmp ax, [1234] ;compare value in ax with value at memory location DS:[1234]
je doStuff  ;if the values are equal then jump to doStuff
doOtherStuff:
  ;do some other things here
doStuff:
add ax, [1234] ;ax = ax + DS:[1234]
...
```

Comment: i understood up to the second line, how do i write "if the values are equal" give me an example

Comment: `je doStuff` does exactly this. `je` is short of "jump if equal". So if value in `ax` is equal to the value at memory location [1234] then the execution continues at label `doStuff`.

Comment: `cmp ax, [1234]` sets up some flags, which instruction `je` check and decides to jump or not to a specified location. These are basic things of assembly language so I would suggest you to check some introduction tutorials on the Internet.

Comment: what if i want to activate an activity at a specified  port address how do i do that